# What is the easiest way to insert data into a relational database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

I have a relational database set up and I want to be able to insert data in an intuitive manner despite the normalization. For instance, I have a table for "ideals" and another table for "actions that this ideal promotes." However, I want to insert this data like a backwards view. I want to be able to list an "ideal" and then just list as many actions as I want in the same window. There has to be some best practice for this kind of thing. How should I got about this?

EDIT: data will only be editing my me. It will never be edited by users. So I want to know how to edit this data in sqlite DBBrowser, not in a UI.

Comment: "in the same window" -- What kind of *window* you're talking about? It's seems like this might be more of a UI design/programming question -- maybe how to let the user define a list of "actions" in a new "ideal" window -- than directly on relational databases.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: *I want to know how to edit this data in sqlite* SQLite does not come with a UI. You can use "Command Line Shell For SQLite": https://sqlite.org/cli.html, which is not what you want. Use a tool like DB Browser for SQLite: https://sqlitebrowser.org (or other), or you can create your app with a programming language that will access the db.

Comment: Sorry. I meant DBrowser.

Comment: You can browse, filter, insert, update and delete data with DB Browser, but its UI is not customizable to the extend you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to insert your data into *views* and not *tables*.

Many databases support triggers on views.  So, you define the "intuitive" views that you want.  Then you write the triggers that do the appropriate manipulations to the underlying tables.

If your data is starting out in a file, then you can use an alternative approach.  You would load the file into a staging table and then use a stored procedure to convert the staging table into the appropriate underlying tables.

Comment: I think I left out an important detail, which is that my data will only be edited by me, never users. I just want an easy way to edit this data in tables in sqlite.